# JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder always adds Connection: close to the Request Headers when intercepting requests

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to intercept requests from my mobile app. On some app screens, the requests need to be sent with Connection: keep-alive. But the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder always adds the "Connection: close" header when intercepting requests. I don't know why, but that makes the HTTP response incorrect and causes my app to fail on some screens. So I cannot record all the requests after that.

I say that the requests need to be sent with Connection: keep-alive because I compare the requests from JMeter and BurpSuite. The only difference is the Connection header: Connection: close for JMeter and Connection: keep-alive for BurpSuite. Everything works well with BurpSuite.

[image: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder always adds the "Connection: close" header]

The HTTP version of the requests is HTTP/1.1. For HTTP/1.1, the default value of the Connection header is keep-alive if not specified, as stated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection#directives.

How can I configure the Jmeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder to either add the Connection: keep-alive header or avoid setting the Connection: close header when intercepting requests?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By default [it doesn't](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

[image]

[image]

So double check your HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder configuration.

---

If you have already recorded your script and would like to send Connection header with the value of `keep-alive` for all [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

1. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) to your test plan (can be empty)
2. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) to your Test Plan
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (sampler instanceof org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase) {
       sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed('Connection')
       sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header('Connection', 'keep-alive'))
   }
   ```

Comment: Tks for your response. I have already enabled the Use Keep-Alive option. And, as far as I know, the Use Keep-Alive option is to set the Connection header for the "generated" samplers. But what I want is to set the Connection header for the "intercepted" requests that happen when I click the Start button in the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder to intercept and then create the generated samplers.

Comment: I apologize if my poor choice of words confused you.